# xtk with GWT: "Uncaught Error: Could not find the given container or it has an undefined size."

Tags: gwt, xtk

Has anybody used XTK with GWT? No matter what I do I get this error "Uncaught Error: Could not find the given container or it has an undefined size."

I have defined the container  element in the base html (below), which is accesible via other means (DOM, JQuery, GWT-JSNI), but not by XTK library.

My GWT-JSNI method and container HTML are as following.

Any help or pointers to debug further?

```
/* GWT JSNI method */
public native void initializeWebgl() /*-{

    alert('r ' + $doc.getElementById('r')); // works

    var r = new $wnd.X.renderer('r'); // fails ??????? why?
    alert("r is" + r);
    r.init(); }*-/
```

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

<noscript>
  <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
    Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
    in order for this application to display correctly.
  </div>
</noscript>

<div id="r" style="background-color: #000000; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This error was observed in some cases. The check which lets the renderer initialization fail is deprecated and already removed on the 'refactoring' branch. So, soon, this should work out of the box.

2) For now, the simplest workaround is to set the renderer to a fixed height (for testing):

```
<div id="r" style="background-color: #000000; width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```

3) It is possible to use CSS to define a min-height on the renderer if the parent element has height 100%. Here information: http://www.gn-webdesign.de/css-tutorials/css-div-height-100.html

Comment: Hi haehn - thanks for the reply. yes, after going through the XTK code and then going through the closure code, i figured out that the problem is with the height of the container div. for now i have a work around using  Window.getClientHeight, Window.getClientWidth (both GWT calls) to create <div> element at runtime with computed dimensions. Obviously I would like to wait for the next release. Is there any mailing list that I can sign-up to receive release announcement? (sorry couldnt find anywhere). Also, I didnt find any notion of release numbers for XTK. Have I missed something?